# Grub is broken again, this time I can't repair

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a dual PC, I use Ubuntu as main OS and have a Windows 10 for some tasks. When I installed Grub was correct and I could select any OS to start up. From time to time it got broken and normally an `update-grub` or a `boot repair` solved the problem, but last time grub didn't get repaired and I can't access Windows 10.

And the thing got worse, as after that, I was messing up trying to install and run Wine and now I think I have some *multi arch* stuff that I cannot completly remove and is interfering with grub repair. Any ideas what might be happening? Where to look a log for the problem?

BTW, I have and UEFI board, UEFI boot is supposed to be disable

This is my boot repair log: http://paste2.org/8DFAhd60

Comment: UEFI boot can't be disabled, win 10 needs it. Please check it

Comment: Windows 10 can be installed in BIOS boot mode. But Windows 10 still has its always on hibernation or fast start up. Updates (often in back ground) may turn on Windows fast start up and/or restore Windows boot loader to MBR. Often easier if Windows is UEFI as then you can directly boot it from UEFI. You may have to temporarily reinstall a Windows boot loader to fix Windows then restore grub. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Well, I'm actually not very sure about what UEFI is, I disbled something related in BIOS, the thing is I've been able to dual boot for some time.

Comment: @oldfred added boot repair link

Comment: It looks like you have the 35 year old BIOS boot using MBR(msdos) partitioning, but top part of Summary report is missing? You are the second one I have seen, does Boot-Repair now have a bug on posting report?

Comment: Sorry, it was **secure boot** what I disabled

Comment: 35 years old BIOS? The mother board I bought was cheap but not old and it has a modern BIOS, all color and I can use the mouse! :-) About restore Windows boot I find it risky, it's my work computer and if this happens from time to time I even prefer to buy a second hand computer for Windows

Comment: That boot repair log is before messing with Wine, no I can't even execute `sudo apt-get purge -y --force-yes grub*-common grub-common:i386 shim-signed linux-signed*` I get erros (BTW I have 64 bits arch)

Comment: Last log: http://paste2.org/O2ghtg3z

Comment: Did you use 'upate-grub' after using grub repair?

Comment: @SharadGautam yes I did, before and after